# gdata BadAuthenticationServiceURL error

Tags: python, gdata, gdata-api

I've been using [a simple script](https://code.google.com/p/youtube-upload) that uses gdata. Recently, without provocation, it started failing with `gdata.service.BadAuthenticationServiceURL: Server responded with a 302 code` during the standard login attempt.

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

After much investigations, it turned out that an upgrade to the latest `gdata` package solved this issue for me.

Comment: It was probably the change in accepted authentication protocols.